# Integrating composer's autoloader into Magento

Tags: composer

So [composer](http://getcomposer.org/) is awesome, and there's a lot of code in composer's [packagist](https://packagist.org/) repository that makes writing Magento extensions easier.

The problem I'm facing, is how best to (cleanly) setup autoloading.

By default composer packages get installed to /vendor, and inside of that directory is an autoload.php file which sets up classloading for the composer managed packages.

So what would be the best way to require_once composer's '/vendor/autoload.php' file? This would need to work for both the webstore and shell scripts. Is there an observer event I can tap to do the require_once?

Cheers!

Comment: No clue if https://github.com/magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer is of any help here. I think its pretty unrelated. I think you try to install non-Magento packages with composer and want to basically have them in lib/

Comment: Yeah you can set composer to install to lib if you choose, but I want to keep composer libs/mage libs separate if possible. Also in composer you can have neat things like classmapped autoloading which doesn't fit with the Mage autoloader mechanism.

Comment: I know that this was answered a long time ago, but another option is to include the vendor autoloader in your index.php file (before `require_once $mageFilename` is called). This works well for client installations, and takes no rewriting files at all.

Comment: Well you're hacking a core file, index.php. When you upgrade, you'll need to remember you added that line of code to index.php.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Magento autoloader is registered in `Mage.php`.

If want to do this in a own module, you should grab the first event possible and require the autoloader there

According to [Alan's analysis](http://magento-quickies.tumblr.com/post/32402056167/magento-startup-events) this would be `resource_get_tablename` - but you have to make sure your only handle this event once.

The quick-and-dirty solution would be to patch `Mage.php` (the very start of the file) - but this is hacking the core.

Also we have the [Magento-PSR-0-Autoloader](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Magento-PSR-0-Autoloader) module, which offers a way to add composers autoloading via config. Its a basic implementation which makes use of the `resource_get_tablename` event.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that's perfect. I had patched mage.php but didn't want to put that in production. observing resource_get_tablename worked fine!

Comment: Vinai had a great suggestion too to put Varien_Autoload  in the local code pool and put the necessary code there which avoids expensive observer events and patching core code directly.

Comment: "Simple implementation of the above example: https://github.com/thijssnowcountry/magento1_composer_loader" -- @user2594875